# При ajax запросе на php файл ничего не приходит

Tags: php, ajax

Не получается отправить запрос на php файл. Вроде запрос уходит, но на странице filter.php, куда я отправляю  пусто. Буду рад любой помощи

```
<form >
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1"></label>
    <select class="form-control"  name="custom" id="select">
      <option class="js-button" value="16">Ventura HRL</option>
      <option class="js-button">2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
 <input type="button" id="js-button" name="done" value="Отправить" style="margin-top: 5px;">
    <p id="js-result"></p>
</form>



<script>
$('#js-button').click(function(){
    var value = $('#select').val();

console.log("wewe"); 

$.ajax({
    url: '/filter.php',        
    method: 'POST',  
 contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8"   ,       
    dataType: 'JSON', 
async: false,        
    data: {section:value },     
    success: function(data){  
        alert("dsdsd");          
    }
});
});
</script>



//filter.php
<?var_dump($_POST);?>
```

Comment: А что там, на этой странице должно быть?

Comment: Отображаться то, что отправил ajax

Comment: Ну так ты и не должен видеть что там на странице filter.php. Ответ тебе придет в `data` параметре в функции `success` и текущая страница не должна перезагружаться.

Comment: Отправка заработает, если удалите 2 строки `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", dataType: 'JSON',`

Comment: @TemirStack, спасибо, но ничего не передается

Comment: Надо смотреть в консоль разработчика на стороне js скрипта. возможно там есть ошибки в консоли... вместо `alert("dsdsd");` написали бы `console.log(data)` и посмотрели бы в консоли что пришло..... а ещё через отладчик посмотреть ответ можно........

Comment: Также неизвестно что написано в PHP коде......... но смотреть надо именно на клиенте.... в этом и смысл ajax: отправить данные на сервер и получить от него ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS замените на это

```
$('#js-button').click(function(){
  var optVal = $('#select').val();
  $.ajax({
      url: 'filter.php',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {section: optVal},
      success: function(data){
        alert(data);
      }
  });
});
```

А это содержимое filter.php

```
<?
    echo "filter.php получил и вернул:\n"; print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

В **`filter.php`** ничего и не должно появиться.
Это обработчик, он должен вернуть результат выполнения. 
Выводите `data` в консоль вместо `alert`.

Еще можно добавить в **`filter.php`** распечатку входящего массива `$_POST` в файл и посмотреть, доходит ли что-то вообще.

Еще как вариант, попробуйте убрать слэш из `url`, если обработчик лежит на одном уровне.